# Indicating a matrix element of an image by a color

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to attach a color code to a specific element of a matrix. But unable to do so. Specifying the color should surface in the new image.

```
I=imread('1.tif')
J=rgb2gray(I)
M=imresize(J,[156 156])
H=imread(M,M(120,134),'red')
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: you want to plot the whole image in gray and one element in red? plot_M=repmat(M,[1,1,3]);plot_M(120,134,:)=[255,0,0];image(plot_M);